# Randomly select rows under conditions

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

On my spreadsheet I have the following dataset

```
ID         pack
1          a
1          b
1          c
2          a
3          c
4          a
4          c
```

I would like to use a function in excel that selects randomly one of the rows where the ID is not unique (it's not important which one, but I need it to be the only one per ID), otherwise has to repeat the same row.

The result according to example should be as below:

```
ID         pack
1          b
2          a
3          c
4          c
```

I tried to add a third column called **count** (counts the number of times the ID is repeated in the db) and calculating a new field as

```
IF(**count**=1,1,RANDBETWEEN(0,1))
```

but in some cases an ID (with multiple packs) gets always 0, in other cases gets always 1.

```
ID         pack    count    check
1          a       3        1
1          b       3        0       
1          c       3        0
2          a       1        1
3          c       1        1
4          a       2        0
4          c       2        0
```

Of course, last step of this is a new column with

```
IF(**check**=1,**pack_name**,0)
```

Comment: How are you getting your unique list of IDs (e.g. *1, 2, 3, 4*)?

Comment: sorry, the list of unique IDs is just a pivot on original dataset, excluding **check** column where value is different from 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your ID's supplied use this formula:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$8)/($A$2:$A$8=D2),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF(A:A,D2))))
```

Put in E2 then copy/drag down.

Then hit F9 and it will randomly choose a different output that matches the ID.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you explain me what are the parameters 15,6 after "aggregate" function, please?

edit: found it 

https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/aggregate.php

Comment: 15 is for the SMALL function, and 6 is to ignore errors, as we force `#DIV/0` errors when the `($A$2:$A$8=D2)` is false.

Comment: Nice formula btw; near duplicate to the one I prepared (a few minutes too late).

Comment: @Jeeped I bet you put in the dynamic ranges in the AGGREGATE.